# I can't find an app that I purchased (wasn't free) anywhere?

Tags: iphone, applications

There is an app called "Calum Von Moger Fitness" and I bought it and stupidly deleted and then when I tried to find it again I couldn't! Strangely I cannot find it in my app purchase history.

I am not happy because I paid for this app and it just disappeared!

Comment: How does this get 2 upvotes? It's not even a question…. Life's like that. App no longer updated, eventually removed from app store as it will no longer run in the current iOS. it happens.

Comment: But its not right? i paid money for it and now i can't reload it? this is scandal!

Comment: Can you not find the question in what i wrote? do you not know what the hell I am asking? and how am I suppose to know that Apple can just remove an app that people pay for? there you are 3 questions. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **What Do I Do When Apple Removes an App I Bought from the App Store?**
>   Back it up! Although Apple does have the power to remotely disable apps on your iDevice, it's not a power they've been known to exercise. If you have a copy of an app they've killed, you should be able to continue to use it. The problem arises, however, when you delete that app. Once it's gone, it's gone—they're not giving you another copy to download. You have to be responsible for backing up that app.

Source : [Lifehacker : What Do I Do When Apple Removes an App I Bought from the App Store?](http://lifehacker.com/5867673/what-do-i-do-when-apple-removes-an-app-i-bought-from-the-app-store)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You said ? Sometimes, it's just enough. Because the most of Ask Different question are not googled before...

Comment: Consider investing *more* than enough into an answer. This will be no good to anyone if the link is removed - what if that link breaks at some point? I've also flagged this so we will see what the mods think of this link only answer. Without the link this is just an anti-apple rant.

Comment: @Tim ... Get pleasure

Comment: Hu? Get what?..

Answer (score 2):

Not available in the U.S. App Store:

"The item you've requested is not currently available in the U.S. Store, but it is available in the Ireland Store. Click Change Store to view this item."

Comment: Not available in UK store but available in New Zealand Store too.